# Does new block device always appear in the /dev directory?

Tags: udev

I'm wondering, if it is possible for a new block device (e.g. SCSI/USB data disk device) connected, to show up somewhere else, than in the `/dev` directory?

Btw, let's not consider symlinks appearing in `/dev/disk` nor `/dev/block`.

---

NOTE: I've already read an answer to [What does /dev/sda for linux mean](https://superuser.com/questions/558156/what-does-dev-sda-for-linux-mean), but I'm still unsure about my question.

Comment: Are you thinking about some particular device, that is not appearing in `/dev` ? Please explain with some details, what makes you ask this question.

Comment: I'm only interested about any type of data disk. That can be external disk, internal disk, USB disk, SD card .. just any type of device you can save data on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In recent systems, a special virtual filesystem (`devtmpfs`) is mounted on `/dev`:

```
$ findmnt /dev
TARGET SOURCE FSTYPE   OPTIONS
/dev   udev   devtmpfs rw,nosuid,relatime,size=1000388k,nr_inodes=250097,mode=755
```

You can mount `devtmpfs` elsewhere and whatever's in `/dev` will appear there too:

```
$ sudo mount -t devtmpfs udev /mnt
$ ls /mnt/sda*
/mnt/sda  /mnt/sda1  /mnt/sda2  /mnt/sda5
```

---

Alternately, you could use `udev` to populate another directory in addition to `/dev`.

---

Aside from such tricks, nope. The devtmpfs filesystem is automatically populated by the kernel. Wherever that filesystem is mounted, the devices will show up there.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you :)